# Abandoned Cart emails with Ampscrip & HTML

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, journeybuilder

I am trying to create an abandoned browse email where multiple products pull through. In this email the products go under each other. How can I get them to go next to each other?

Below is the HTML & ampscript of what we are currently using in our template:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0px; padding:0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none;" yahoo="fix">
    <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <div align="center">
                        <table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="container" style="width: 640px;max-width: 640px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">%%[SET @DateSent = Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy") Var @email , @UID, @MemberID, @ItemID, @MarketingCloudVisitorID, @OriginalItemID, @Family ,@FullProdImage ,@FullProdImageLand ,@FullProdImagePort ,@FullProdUrl ,@isNew ,@ItemName ,@ItemsPrimaryCategoryID ,@MaxCredits ,@PriceRange ,@ProdImage ,@ProdImageLand ,@ProdImagePort ,@Products ,@ProdUrl, @Revenue, @Units
 IF NOT EMPTY(UserID) THEN SET @email = UserID endif SET @UID = UniversalID SET @MemberID = [MemberID] SET @ItemID = [Item ID] SET @MarketingCloudVisitorID = [Marketing Cloud Visitor ID] SET @OriginalItemID = [Original Item ID] SET @Family = Family SET @FullProdImage = FullProdImage SET @FullProdImageLand = FullProdImageLand SET @FullProdImagePort = FullProdImagePort SET @FullProdUrl = FullProdUrl SET @isNew = isNew SET @ItemName = [Item Name] SET @ItemsPrimaryCategoryID = [Items Primary Category ID] SET @MaxCredits = [Max Credits] SET @PriceRange = [Price Range] SET @ProdImage = Concat('https://www.aicpastore.com',[ProdImage]) SET @ProdImageLand = Concat('https://www.aicpastore.com',[ProdImageLand]) SET @ProdImagePort = Concat('https://www.aicpastore.com',[ProdImagePort]) SET @Products = [Products] SET @ProdUrl = Concat('https://www.aicpastore.com',[ProdUrl]) SET @Revenue = [Revenue]
SET @Units = [Units]

var @Rows, @Row, @rowCount

set @Rows = LookupRows("RemarketingTestnoPK","UserID", @email)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@Rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
    for @counter = 1 to rowcount(@Rows) do
        set @Row = row(@Rows,@counter)
        set @ItemName = field(@row,"Item Name")
    next @counter
endif

 ]%%
</td></tr></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                           <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><table style="max-width: 680px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td style="color:#63656b; padding-top: 13px; padding-bottom: 13px; font-family: Roboto thin, Arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 300;" valign="top" align="center">
    %%=v(@preheader)=%%</td></tr><tr>
   <td valign="top" align="center">
    <table class="container" width="680" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

      <tr>
       <td style="line-height: 1px;" valign="top" height="1" bgcolor="#c7c8ca" align="center">
        <img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9813737561027c74/m/1/Spacer.gif" style="display: block;" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>

                                </td>
                            </tr>                                                                                   
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- Logo and Menu: BEGIN --><!-- dir=ltr is where the magic happens. This can be changed to dir=rtl to swap the alignment on wide while maintaining stack order on narrow. --><!--[if mso]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                        <![endif]--><table role="presentation" style="max-width:680px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td style="font-size:0; padding: 10px 0;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
    <!--[if mso]>
                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="230" style="width: 230px;">
                                    <![endif]--><div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width: 230px; min-width:230px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
     <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

       <tr>
        <td dir="ltr" style="padding: 0 10px 0px 10px;" valign="bottom">
         <a alias="aicpa" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="alt_text" class="center-on-narrow" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/images/storelogo_new.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 230px; height: auto;" width="230" border="0"></a></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="428" style="width: 428px;">
                                    <![endif]--><div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width:428px; min-width:300px; vertical-align:top;">
     <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

       <tr>
        <td class="center-on-narrow mmenu" dir="ltr" style="font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 13px; line-height: 21px; color: #72246c;font-weight:; padding: 30px 10px 10px 10px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
         <a alias="cpe" conversion="true" data-linkto="https://" href="https://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Responsive_Top_Nav/Certificates.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Certificates&nbsp;&gt;</a> <a alias="conf" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Top/Browse/Primary/Conferences.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Conferences&nbsp;&gt;</a> <a alias="pubs" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Top/Browse/Primary/Publications.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Publications&nbsp;&gt;</a> <a alias="cpe" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Top/Browse/Primary/CPE.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Self-study&nbsp;&gt;</a> <a alias="webcasts" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Top/Browse/Primary/Webcasts.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Webcasts&nbsp;&gt;</a></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]--></td></tr></table><!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]--><!-- Logo and Menu : END --></td></tr></table>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- A1 (text with no images) : BEGIN --><table role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px;background-color:#DC6B2F" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td class="mtext" style="padding: 25px 50px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 23px;text-align: left; color: #ffffff;">
    Still Shopping?</td></tr></table><!-- A1 (text with no images) : END --></td></tr></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- A2 (callout block area) : BEGIN --><table role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td class="mtext" style="padding: 25px 50px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 17px; line-height: 23px;color:#63656b">
    <br>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 19px">Thanks for stopping by the AICPA Store. Come back and give our products another look...</span></td></tr></table><!-- A2 (callout block area) : END --></td></tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">%%[ 
 var @Rows, @Row, @rowCount

 set @Rows = LookupRows("RemarketingTestnoPK","UserID", @email) 
 set @rowCount = rowcount(@Rows) 
 if @rowCount > 0 then 
  for @counter = 1 to rowcount(@Rows) do 
   set @Row = row(@Rows,@counter) 
   set @FullProdImagePort = field(@row,"FullProdImagePort") 
    set @FullProdURL = field(@row,"FullProdURL") 

if indexOf(@FullProdURL,'?') > 0 then 
set @parameter = "&"
else
set @parameter = "?"
endif

set @fullURL = Concat(@FullProdURL,@parameter)

    ]%%
 <center><a alias="" href="%%=redirectto(@fullURL)=%%"><img alt="%%=v(@ItemName) =%%" src="%%=v(@FullProdImagePort) =%%" style="height: 279px; width: 207px;" width="207" height="279"></a><center>
   <p></p> 
        <p>
                   </p>   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td align="center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td class="innertd buttonblock" style=" border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #72246C;" bgcolor="#72246C"><a target="_blank" class="buttonstyles" style=" font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; background-color: #72246C; border: 1px solid #72246C; padding: 10px; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;" href="%%=redirectto(@fullURL)=%%" title="productlink" alias="" conversion="true" data-linkto="other">Learn More</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
           <p>

           </p>
%%[ 
  next @counter 
 endif
]%% </center></center>
</td></tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- A2 (callout block area) : BEGIN --><table role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td class="mtext" style="padding: 25px 50px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 17px; line-height: 23px;color:#63656b">
    Let us help you select the products you need &mdash; for you and your business. If you need additional information about a product, please call us at <b>888.777.7077</b>.</td></tr></table><!-- A2 (callout block area) : END --></td></tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- Black Footer Bar : BEGIN --><!-- dir=ltr is where the magic happens. This can be changed to dir=rtl to swap the alignment on wide while maintaining stack order on narrow. --><!--[if mso]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                        <![endif]--><table role="presentation" style="max-width:680px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td style="font-size:0; padding: 6px 0 6px 0;" valign="top" align="center">
    <!--[if mso]>
                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="660" style="width: 660px;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="340" style="width: 340px;">
                                    <![endif]--><div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width:66.66%; min-width:320px; vertical-align:top;">
     <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

       <tr>
        <td class="center-on-narrow" dir="ltr" style="font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px; color: #ffffff; padding: 10px 27px 6px 27px; text-align: left;">
         <a alias="AICPASTORE" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">AICPASTORE.com</a></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="220" style="width: 220px;">
                                    <![endif]--><div class="center-on-narrow" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width: 200px; min-width:160px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
     <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

       <tr>
        <td class="m_icons" style="padding: 6px 10px 0px 10px; text-align: center;" align="center">
         <table width="140" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">

           <tr>
            <td align="center">
             <a alias="facebook" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.facebook.com/aicpa" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="facebook" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/cheetahmail/cpa.com/iconb-fb.gif" style="display:block;" width="30" border="0"></a></td><td align="center">
             <a alias="twitter" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.twitter.com/aicpa" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="twitter" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/cheetahmail/cpa.com/iconb-tw.gif" style="display:block;" width="30" border="0"></a></td><td align="center">
             <a alias="linkedin" conversion="true" data-linkto="https://" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/aicpa/" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="linkedin" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/cheetahmail/cpa.com/iconb-in.gif" style="display:block;" width="30" border="0"></a></td><td align="center">
             <a alias="blog" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://blog.aicpa.org/" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="rss" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/cheetahmail/cpa.com/iconb-rss.gif" style="display:block;" width="30" border="0"></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]--></td></tr></table><!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]--><!-- Black Footer Bar : END --><table role="presentation" style="max-width:680px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td class="mtext" style="padding: 10px 15px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 12px; 
mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #63656b;" width="57%" valign="top">
    <strong>You are Subscribed to the Products Mailing List</strong><br>
    <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="https://account.aicpa.org/eWeb/DynamicPage.aspx?webcode=tabOnlineComm" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Manage Your Preferences</a><br>
    <a alias="unsub" conversion="true" data-linkto="other" href="%%profile_center_url%%" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Unsubscribe</a><br>
    <a alias="add to address book" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/Content/media/Producer_content/generic_template_content/add2_address_book.jsp" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Add to Address Book</a><br>
    <a alias="privacy policy" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Footer/General_Site_Information/Privacy_Policy.jsp" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Privacy Policy</a><br>
    <a alias="contact us" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Footer/Customer_Service/Contact_Us.jsp" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Contact Us</a><br>
    <br>
    <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height:14px; color:#63656b">&copy; 2019 Association of International Certified Professional Accountants. All rights reserved.</span></td><td class="mtext" style="padding: 10px 15px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 12px;" width="43%" valign="top" align="left">
    <div style="line-height: 23px;">
     <b style="color: rgb(99, 101, 107);">%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>
     <font color="#63656b">%%Member_Addr%%</font><br>
     <font color="#63656b">%%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%</font><br>
     <font color="#63656b">888.777.7077</font><br>
     <font color="#999999">xxxx</font></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Is there a way for when the product images pulled form the data extension can be pulled in vertically instead of horizontally? (next to each other, instead of underneath).

Comment: HI Jennifer, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the tour and read How to Ask. Right now, this post would be improved if you edit it to be more specific and also to contain a question. A good Question post will outline very clearly the behavior you expect and the behavior you observe, and contain a clear question which can be answered succinctly. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Adding to Jackson Chen's comment, this sounds like something that you'll need to provide your ampscript and/or email template for (and the fix, if possible, will likely involve modifying your email template). You should [edit] your question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple closing of `<tr><td>` tags issue. Remove the complexity of the for loop and build your HTML correctly before you add in AMPscript logic.

[image: screenshot]

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0px; padding:0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none;" yahoo="fix">
    <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <div align="center">
                        <table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="container" style="width: 640px;max-width: 640px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">




</td></tr></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                           <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><table style="max-width: 680px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td style="color:#63656b; padding-top: 13px; padding-bottom: 13px; font-family: Roboto thin, Arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 300;" valign="top" align="center">
    %%=v(@preheader)=%%</td></tr><tr>
   <td valign="top" align="center">
    <table class="container" width="680" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

      <tr>
       <td style="line-height: 1px;" valign="top" height="1" bgcolor="#c7c8ca" align="center">
        <img src="http://image.s7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9813737561027c74/m/1/Spacer.gif" style="display: block;" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>

                                </td>
                            </tr>                                                                                   
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- Logo and Menu: BEGIN --><!-- dir=ltr is where the magic happens. This can be changed to dir=rtl to swap the alignment on wide while maintaining stack order on narrow. --><!--[if mso]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                        <![endif]--><table role="presentation" style="max-width:680px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td style="font-size:0; padding: 10px 0;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
    <!--[if mso]>
                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="230" style="width: 230px;">
                                    <![endif]--><div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width: 230px; min-width:230px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
     <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

       <tr>
        <td dir="ltr" style="padding: 0 10px 0px 10px;" valign="bottom">
         <a alias="aicpa" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="alt_text" class="center-on-narrow" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/images/storelogo_new.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 230px; height: auto;" width="230" border="0"></a></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="428" style="width: 428px;">
                                    <![endif]--><div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width:428px; min-width:300px; vertical-align:top;">
     <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

       <tr>
        <td class="center-on-narrow mmenu" dir="ltr" style="font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 13px; line-height: 21px; color: #72246c;font-weight:; padding: 30px 10px 10px 10px; text-align: center;" valign="top">
         <a alias="cpe" conversion="true" data-linkto="https://" href="https://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Responsive_Top_Nav/Certificates.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Certificates&nbsp;&gt;</a> <a alias="conf" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Top/Browse/Primary/Conferences.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Conferences&nbsp;&gt;</a> <a alias="pubs" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Top/Browse/Primary/Publications.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Publications&nbsp;&gt;</a> <a alias="cpe" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Top/Browse/Primary/CPE.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Self-study&nbsp;&gt;</a> <a alias="webcasts" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Top/Browse/Primary/Webcasts.jsp" style="color:#63656b;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">Webcasts&nbsp;&gt;</a></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]--></td></tr></table><!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]--><!-- Logo and Menu : END --></td></tr></table>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- A1 (text with no images) : BEGIN --><table role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px;background-color:#DC6B2F" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td class="mtext" style="padding: 25px 50px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 23px;text-align: left; color: #ffffff;">
    Still Shopping?</td></tr></table><!-- A1 (text with no images) : END --></td></tr></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- A2 (callout block area) : BEGIN --><table role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td class="mtext" style="padding: 25px 50px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 17px; line-height: 23px;color:#63656b">
    <br>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 19px">Thanks for stopping by the AICPA Store. Come back and give our products another look...</span></td></tr></table><!-- A2 (callout block area) : END --></td></tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"> 
<tr><td>
 <center><a alias="" href="%%=redirectto(@fullURL)=%%"><img alt="%%=v(@ItemName) =%%" src="%%=v(@FullProdImagePort) =%%" style="height: 279px; width: 207px;" width="207" height="279"></a><center>
   <p></p> 
        <p>
                   </p>   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td align="center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td class="innertd buttonblock" style=" border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #72246C;" bgcolor="#72246C"><a target="_blank" class="buttonstyles" style=" font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; background-color: #72246C; border: 1px solid #72246C; padding: 10px; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;" href="%%=redirectto(@fullURL)=%%" title="productlink" alias="" conversion="true" data-linkto="other">Learn More</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
           <p>

           </p>
</center></center>
    </td><td>                       
 <center><a alias="" href="%%=redirectto(@fullURL)=%%"><img alt="%%=v(@ItemName) =%%" src="%%=v(@FullProdImagePort) =%%" style="height: 279px; width: 207px;" width="207" height="279"></a><center>
   <p></p> 
        <p>
                   </p>   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td align="center"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td class="innertd buttonblock" style=" border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #72246C;" bgcolor="#72246C"><a target="_blank" class="buttonstyles" style=" font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; background-color: #72246C; border: 1px solid #72246C; padding: 10px; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;" href="%%=redirectto(@fullURL)=%%" title="productlink" alias="" conversion="true" data-linkto="other">Learn More</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
           <p>

           </p>
</center></center></td></tr>
</td></tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- A2 (callout block area) : BEGIN --><table role="presentation" style="max-width: 680px" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td class="mtext" style="padding: 25px 50px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 17px; line-height: 23px;color:#63656b">
    Let us help you select the products you need &mdash; for you and your business. If you need additional information about a product, please call us at <b>888.777.7077</b>.</td></tr></table><!-- A2 (callout block area) : END --></td></tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td style="padding: 0px; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><!-- Black Footer Bar : BEGIN --><!-- dir=ltr is where the magic happens. This can be changed to dir=rtl to swap the alignment on wide while maintaining stack order on narrow. --><!--[if mso]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="680" style="width: 680px;">
                        <![endif]--><table role="presentation" style="max-width:680px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td style="font-size:0; padding: 6px 0 6px 0;" valign="top" align="center">
    <!--[if mso]>
                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="660" style="width: 660px;">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="340" style="width: 340px;">
                                    <![endif]--><div class="stack-column" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width:66.66%; min-width:320px; vertical-align:top;">
     <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

       <tr>
        <td class="center-on-narrow" dir="ltr" style="font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px; color: #ffffff; padding: 10px 27px 6px 27px; text-align: left;">
         <a alias="AICPASTORE" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title="">AICPASTORE.com</a></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="220" style="width: 220px;">
                                    <![endif]--><div class="center-on-narrow" style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width: 200px; min-width:160px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
     <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

       <tr>
        <td class="m_icons" style="padding: 6px 10px 0px 10px; text-align: center;" align="center">
         <table width="140" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">

           <tr>
            <td align="center">
             <a alias="facebook" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.facebook.com/aicpa" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="facebook" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/cheetahmail/cpa.com/iconb-fb.gif" style="display:block;" width="30" border="0"></a></td><td align="center">
             <a alias="twitter" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.twitter.com/aicpa" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="twitter" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/cheetahmail/cpa.com/iconb-tw.gif" style="display:block;" width="30" border="0"></a></td><td align="center">
             <a alias="linkedin" conversion="true" data-linkto="https://" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/aicpa/" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="linkedin" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/cheetahmail/cpa.com/iconb-in.gif" style="display:block;" width="30" border="0"></a></td><td align="center">
             <a alias="blog" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://blog.aicpa.org/" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="rss" src="http://media.aicpastore.com/Publication/cheetahmail/cpa.com/iconb-rss.gif" style="display:block;" width="30" border="0"></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div><!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]--></td></tr></table><!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]--><!-- Black Footer Bar : END --><table role="presentation" style="max-width:680px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">

  <tr>
   <td class="mtext" style="padding: 10px 15px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 12px; 
mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #63656b;" width="57%" valign="top">
    <strong>You are Subscribed to the Products Mailing List</strong><br>
    <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="https://account.aicpa.org/eWeb/DynamicPage.aspx?webcode=tabOnlineComm" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Manage Your Preferences</a><br>
    <a alias="unsub" conversion="true" data-linkto="other" href="%%profile_center_url%%" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Unsubscribe</a><br>
    <a alias="add to address book" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/Content/media/Producer_content/generic_template_content/add2_address_book.jsp" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Add to Address Book</a><br>
    <a alias="privacy policy" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Footer/General_Site_Information/Privacy_Policy.jsp" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Privacy Policy</a><br>
    <a alias="contact us" conversion="true" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.aicpastore.com/AST/AICPA_CPA2BiZ_Nav/Footer/Customer_Service/Contact_Us.jsp" style="color:#72246c;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="">Contact Us</a><br>
    <br>
    <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height:14px; color:#63656b">&copy; 2019 Association of International Certified Professional Accountants. All rights reserved.</span></td><td class="mtext" style="padding: 10px 15px; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-size: 12px;" width="43%" valign="top" align="left">
    <div style="line-height: 23px;">
     <b style="color: rgb(99, 101, 107);">%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>
     <font color="#63656b">%%Member_Addr%%</font><br>
     <font color="#63656b">%%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%</font><br>
     <font color="#63656b">888.777.7077</font><br>
     <font color="#999999">xxxx</font></div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```